# In DNN how to disable a parent menu link  for the NON HOST, NON admin?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

In one of my DNN web site i am using DNN menu, for some item in DNN menu i want the parent or root menu item to be accessible by HOST user, or admin user and want child elements to be accessible all users so how can i disable all root menu item to be enabled for the host/admin only(it should be click-able and should redirect to appropriate link) while the sub menu item for the root item should be enabled for all users. I am in dire need of solution please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a strange setup that you want with this.

To disable a parent menu link, you just set the page properties to 'disabled'.  This makes a page not clickable in the menu.

However, if for some reason you want admins to be able to click a menu item, but no other users, then I would suggest that you set up the parent menu item as normal, but then set that page to have a permanent redirect to a different page, with the second page hidden.  The second page would then have the permissions set to only be visible by admin/host users.

So...

parent  : enabled, visible, all users permission, permanent redirect to 'fake parent'
  child page 1 : as normal
  child page 2 : as normal
  child page n : as normal, etc

somewhere else in the menu.
fake parent : hidden page, admin only permission

It would be a bit clunky but probably will work OK.

Answer (score 0):

In DNN 9.00.01 the Disabled option is not there.So in that case u need to Go to your DNN database and update the `Tabs table` `DisableLink` Column value from `0` to `1`